# How to trim the space from the lpApplicationName of the CreateProcessW function?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am using CreateProcessW function to create a process. Into this function, passing the first parameter i.e., lpApplicationName with some spaces like as shown below:

In the below path (pszExePath) there are spaces because of this process is not creating.

```
pszExePath = L"C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Installer\\emrinst.exe";
```

I tried to trim the space by using the below lines but still i am facing the issue.

```
pszExePath = L"\"";
pszExePath += L"C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Installer\\emrinst.exe";
pszExePath += L"\"";
```

How to trim the space from the lpApplicationName of the CreateProcessW function?

**Below is the updated code:**

```
pszExePath = L"C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Installer\\emrinst.exe";
strCommandLine = "C:\\Testfolder\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Apps\\emarmain\\emr-test_folder\\Millinnium Files\\test\\test.inf";

std::wstring strFullPath = L"";
strFullPath += pszExePath;
strFullPath += pszCmdLine;


dwExitCode = ::CreateProcessW(NULL, (LPWSTR)strFullPath.c_str(),
            0, 0, FALSE, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, 0,
            pszCurrentDirectory, &si, &pi);
```

still I am getting the error, I think it is exceeding the size of the second parameter "lpCommandLine" of 32,768 characters. Is there any way to increase the size? And also is my code snippet is correct?

Comment: I'm not sure what space you're talking about nor how "trimming" will help. (I suspect you mean something other than trim.)

Comment: I am asking about space between "Program Files" and also "Common Files"? If I keep "emrinst.exe" with the path that has no spaces then it is working.

Comment: 2 of the 4 string literals are missing an L in front of them Without the L, it is an ASCII string literal.

Comment: @JohnPaulCoder Show the declaration of `pszExePath` and how you use it in your calll to `CreateProcessW` in your question please.

Comment: @JohnPaulCoder Trimming usually refers to the removal of something. You don't want to remove the spaces, do you?

Comment: you need exactly path to exe in *lpApplicationName* - exist space in path, not exist space - not play any role. *there are spaces because of this process is not creating.* this is wrong, if process not created - exist another reason

Comment: It should be easy to see the problem if you provide a [mcve], with error checking included, and if you tell us what the error code is

Comment: exe path and command line must be both unicode or both ansi. what you need make `strCommandLine` also unicode

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Following the MSDN documentation for [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) (Unicode) and the code in the question:

1) Add double quotes to the EXE path and the command line.

2) Add whitespace between the `pszExePath` and `strCommandLine`.

3) Note: This solution requires a C++11 since `CreateProcess` requires a non-read only string as `lpCommandLine` parameter. For prior versions of C++, use `_wcsdup` to duplicate the string and call for `free` to release it.

```
    std::wstring pszExePath     = L"C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Installer\\emrinst.exe";
    std::wstring strCommandLine = L"C:\\Testfolder\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Apps\\emarmain\\emr-test_folder\\Millinnium Files\\test\\test.inf";

    std::wstring strFullPath = L"\"" + pszExePath + L"\"" + L" " + L"\"" + strCommandLine + L"\"";

    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    STARTUPINFO si;
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof si;      

    BOOL result = ::CreateProcessW(NULL, &strFullPath[0], 0, 0, FALSE, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, 0, pszCurrentDirectory, &si, &pi);    

    if (result)
    {
       CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
       CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    }
```

**Edit:**
Alternatively, you could try [ShellExecuteW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutew) (pay attention to double quotes in both paths).

```
std::wstring pszExePath = L"\"C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Installer\\emrinst.exe\"";
std::wstring strCommandLine = L"\"C:\\Testfolder\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Apps\\emarmain\\emr-test_folder\\Millinnium Files\\test\\test.inf\"";

ShellExecute(0, L"open", pszExePath.c_str(), strCommandLine.c_str(), pszCurrentDirectory, SW_NORMAL);
```

Comment: `_wcsdup()` is unnecessary. You can use `CreateProcessW(NULL, &strFullPath[0], ...)` instead, or `CreateProcessW(NULL, strFullPath.data(), ...)` in C++17 and later.

Comment: Thank you @EyIM, It is working now except the case where the path has special character (-). If the path has special character (for eg, in our case the path has  \\emr-test_folder\\) it is returning with exit code 87 (Invalid parameter)

Comment: When I remove the hyphen from the path (\\emr-test_folder\\), then it is working.

Comment: I've tested the code using notepad.exe and command line with hyphen and I see no problem. I guess the issue might be that the EXE is not accepting the hyphen as parameter.

Comment: @EylM `(LPWSTR)strFullPath.c_str()` is not guaranteed to work prior to C++11. Even `&strFullPath[0]` is not guaranteed to work prior to C++11 either, but it typically will, and doesn't require type-casting a const pointer to a non-const pointer.

Comment: *Add double quotes to the EXE path* - no, this is fatal error. exe path must be exactly file path without any quotes. and why you use 0 in place *pszExePath* ? also when we use no 0 *lpApplicationName* (what is always better) - second parameter can be read only string

Answer (score 3):

As you have no doubt read in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa):

> If you are using a long file name that contains a space, use quoted strings to indicate where the file name ends and the arguments begin; otherwise, the file name is ambiguous.

So you've got that part right, but you can't concatenate C strings like that.  Instead, you can do:

```
#include <string>

std::wstring cmdline = L"\"";
cmdline += L"C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Installer\\emrinst.exe";
cmdline += L"\"";

CreateProcess (NULL, &cmdline [0], ...);
```

Alternatively, you can pass the application path as yhe first parameter of `CreateProcess` without quotes.

Comment: Hi @Paul Sanders, pszExePath  is std::wstring because of that i am using L"\"";

Comment: @JohnPaulCoder We can't tell if that's the case because you haven't shown the declaration of `pszExePath` or how you use it in the call to `CreateProcessW`.

Comment: you confuse command line (2 argument) and application path (1 argument). application path must be without any quata("). answer is wrong.

Comment: but why not use first parameter - *lpApplicationName* ? if we have it. i never can understand this

Comment: @RbMm Well, yes.  It depends on what one has to hand, I guess.

Comment: but in concrete case - we have exactly *lpApplicationName* - `L"C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Installer\\emrinst.exe"` - it must be passed as first parameter to `CreateProcessW` instead 0. and not need any " or other pre process name